# swift 4: How to print text from JSON file?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this JSON file with text and name: 3.json:

```
{
"questions" : [{"text1": "1", "text2": "1"},
               {"text1": "2", "text2": "2"},
               {"text1": "3", "text2": "3"}]
}
```

And I want to print `question, text1, text2` from this file and show it in debug

New code:

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let questions : [Question]
}

struct Question : Decodable {
    let text1, text2 : String
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
let jsonString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "3", ofType: "json")

        do {
            let data = Data(jsonString!.utf8)
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
            for question in result.questions {
                print(question.text1, question.text2)
            }

        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
        }

    }
```

But I have this error:  `dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))
nothing`

How to fix error?

Comment: My advice is to you! kindly use Alamofire for calling json. This library is very effective and also good code practices.

Comment: Thank you! But I also wanted to understand the default methods to use JSON

Comment: specify what's wrong with your code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are responsible for the JSON structure I highly recommend to declare `questions` as an array of dictionaries.

For example

```
let jsonString = """
{
"questions" : [{"text1": "1", "text2": "1"},
                {"text1": "2", "text2": "2"},
                {"text1": "3", "text2": "3"}]
}
"""
```

Then you can create two structs

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let questions : [Question]
}

struct Question : Decodable {
    let text1, text2 : String
}
```

and decode the JSON and print `text1` and `text2` of each question:

```
do {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    for question in result.questions {
        print(question.text1, question.text2)
    }

} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

Copy and paste the code in a Playground to check it out.

After your update get the data with

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "3", withExtension: "json")!
do {
    let data = Data(contentsOf: url)
```

Comment: It is work. But I want to take data from JSON because I have more 100 text1 and text2 with large amount of text. It's very inconvenient to work with so much text... Hot to solve the problem with JSON?

Comment: `jsonString` **is** JSON. Parsing JSON into structs is the most convenient way.

Comment: I not underst. If I have 3 different JSON files I should write a path like this `jsonString  = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "titleOfJson", ofType: "json")`?

Comment: My example creates `Data` from JSON string. You are going to create `Data` from path or `URL` containing JSON string. Both are `Data` representing JSON. I updated the answer. But consider that it works only if the structure of the files matches the JSON structs (over vice versa).

Comment: Ok. I want to to create Data from path bot I have this error: `dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))
nothing
` How to fix it?

Comment: The error message **The given data was not valid JSON.** means what it says: The file does not contain valid JSON.

Comment: I update my question. Please check. Could you tell me what I write wrong in code?

Comment: Thank you! I also asked a new question on this topic. Please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081761/show-text-from-json-with-using-button