# Show text from JSON with using button

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this JSON file with text and name: 0.json:

```
{
"questions" : [{"text1": "1", "text2": "1"},
               {"text1": "2", "text2": "2"},
               {"text1": "3", "text2": "3"}]
}
```

I print `text1, text2` from this file and show it in label

My code:

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let questions : [Question]
}

struct Question : Decodable {
    let text1, text2 : String
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "0", withExtension: "json")!

        do {
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
            for question in result.questions {
                label2.text = "\(question.text2)"
                label1.text = "\(question.text1)"
            }

        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
        }

    }
```

When app starts I want to show first line `"text1": "1", "text2": "1"` and if user clicked on button I want to show second line `"text1": "2", "text2": "2"` and after button clicked I want to show third line `"text1": "3", "text2": "3"` and etc. How to do it?

**Update**
 code:

```
{
    "questions" : [{"number": "1", "text": "1", "answer": "1"},
                   {"number": "2", "text": "2", "answer": "2"},
                   {"number": "3", "text": "3", "answer": "3"}]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "0", withExtension: "json")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
        self.questions = result.questions

        textField.delegate = self
        textField.returnKeyType = .done
        _ = textFieldShouldReturn(textField)

    }

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        let question = questions[counter]
        title = question.number
        textLabel.text = question.text
        showAnswerLabel.text = question.answer
        counter = (counter + 1) % questions.count

        if textField.text == question.answer {
            print("right")

        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Do not perform a for loop: `for question in result.questions`. Just do `let question = result.first; label1.text = question.text1; label2.text = question.text2`. You can use a var to know the current index: `var index`, and init it at zero. When you tap on the button, do `index = index+1`, and `let questionN = result[index]; label1.text = question.text1, etc`. Beware of the out of bounds, and also keep results in a var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create properties for the questions and a counter

  ```
  var questions = [Question]()
  var counter = 0
  ```
- in `viewDidLoad` populate `questions`

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "0", withExtension: "json")!
      let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
      let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
      self.questions = result.questions
   }
  ```
- Create an `IBAction`. In the body get the question for the current `counter` value, assign the text values to the labels and increment the counter. If the counter exceeds the number of items in `questions` reset the counter to 0 (conveniently performed by the `%` operator). Connect the action to the button in Interface Builder

  ```
  @IBAction func push(_ sender : UIButton)
  {
      let question = questions[counter]
      label2.text = question.text2 // no String Interpolation
      label1.text = question.text1
      counter = (counter + 1) % questions.count
  }
  ```

Comment: I have some problem. I added my code in question in Update title. I want to get `right` in debug when I write in textField number from "answer" from JSON. For this line `{"number": "1", "text": "1", "answer": "1"}` right answer is `1`. But when I write `1` in textField for this line I not get `right` in debug. I get `right` in debug for this line if I write in textField `2`. How to fix it?

Comment: Do you understand my problem? What I should do?

Comment: Honestly I don't understand at all what you are going to accomplish. But please ask a new question and provide more information.

Comment: I have a 3 line(questions) in my JSON file. When app start I want to load info from JSON. In `title` I want to load info from `question.number`, in `textLabel.text` I want to load info from `question.text`, in `showAnswerLabel.text` I want to load info from `question.answer`. And when I write in `textField` right answer from `question.answer` and press on done button on keyboard I want to see `print("right")` in console and in my device I want to see the next question. But I have a problem. When app start I load firs line from JSON. And in my `showAnswerLabel.text` answer = 1.

Comment: But when I write `1` in textField and press done button I not get `print("right")` in console. But If I write answer `2` from second line in JSON in textField and press done button I get `print("right")` in console. But right answer should be number from `showAnswerLabel.text` that is `1`. How to fix it?

Comment: I asked new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183879/loading-info-from-json

Comment: I need that user to see the first question from JSON after the application starts. And after the user answer on the question(pressing the done button on the keyboard), he should see the next question from JSON and etc. What is the best way to do this? Maybe my current code is not at all suitable for this task? How to choose the most suitable code?