# Loading info from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a 3 line(questions) in my JSON file. When app start I want to load info from JSON. In `title` I want to load info from `question.number`, in `textLabel.text` I want to load info from `question.text`, in `showAnswerLabel.text` I want to load info from `question.answer`. And when I write in `textField` right answer from `question.answer` and press on done button on keyboard I want to see `print("right")` in console and in my device I want to see the next question. But I have a problem. When app start I load firs line (`{"number": "1", "text": "1", "answer": "1"},`) from JSON. And in my `showAnswerLabel.text` answer = `1`. But when I write `1` in `textField` and press done button I not get `print("right")` in console. But If I write answer = `2` from second line (`{"number": "2", "text": "2", "answer": "2"},`) from JSON in `textField` and press done button I get `print("right")` in console. But right answer should be number from `showAnswerLabel.text` that is `1`. How to fix it?

my new code:

```
{
    "questions" : [{"number": "1", "text": "1", "answer": "1"},
                   {"number": "2", "text": "2", "answer": "2"},
                   {"number": "3", "text": "3", "answer": "3"}]
}

struct Root : Decodable {
    let questions : [Question]
}

struct Question : Decodable {
    let number, text, answer : String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var counter = 0
var questions = [Question]()
@IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var showAnswerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "0", withExtension: "json")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
        self.questions = result.questions

        textField.delegate = self
        textField.returnKeyType = .done
        _ = textFieldShouldReturn(textField)

    }

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        let question = questions[counter]
        title = question.number
        textLabel.text = question.text
        showAnswerLabel.text = question.answer
        counter = (counter + 1) % questions.count

        if textField.text == question.answer {
            print("right")

        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: What's `counter`, a global variable initialized to zero?

Comment: @djromero Updated question

Comment: Try to debug yourself. On viewDidload to setup you UI you executed  you code for the first time. So your `counter` is 1. And when you pressed done, you are settin up your text fileds for second question, and chiking answer for second question.

Comment: Why do you call `_ = textFieldShouldReturn(textField)` in `viewDidLoad`? As @MichaelVorontsov said that's changing `counter` and breaking your logic.

Comment: @djromero If I not call `_ = textFieldShouldReturn(textField)` in `viewDidLoad` I have empty labels when app start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible fix where the UI update is extracted from `textFieldShouldReturn` and binded to the change of `counter`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate 
{
    var questions = [Question]()
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var showAnswerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var counter: Int = -1 {
       didSet {
           guard counter >= 0, counter < questions.count else { fatalError() }       
           let question = questions[counter] 
           updateUI(with: question)
       }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "0", withExtension: "json")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
        self.questions = result.questions
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.returnKeyType = .done

        counter = 0 // will trigger `updateUI(with: questions[0])`
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        let question = questions[counter]        
        if textField.text == question.answer {
            print("right")
            // increment counter only answer is right
            // will trigger an UI update
            counter = (counter + 1) % questions.count 
        }

        return true
    }

    func updateUI(with question: Question) {
        title = question.number
        textLabel.text = question.text
        showAnswerLabel.text = question.answer
    }
}
```

I won't do it exactly like this but you get the idea.

Comment: I habe a problem: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Question'`

Comment: I fixed the glitch. Try now. You may need to fix some other problem, this was just an idea about how to proceed, not intended to be _your final_ code.

Comment: Thank you! It is works. I delete this line `counter = (counter + 1) % questions.count ` from `if textField.text == question.answer` and add under this check `if textField.text == question.answer` because I want to show next question if answer was wrong too.

Comment: I have a small question. I need the user to see the first question from JSON after the application starts. And after the user answer on the question(pressing the done button on the keyboard), he should see the next question from JSON and etc. What is the best way to do this? Maybe my current code is not at all suitable for this task? How to choose the most suitable code?

Comment: When you modify `counter` the UI will update. In my example I changed `counter` only in the answer is right, you can change it always if that's what you need.